# Java socks 4 proxy issue

Tags: java, sockets, io, java-io

I've setup java to use SOCK4 by utilizing reflection call java.net.SocksSocketImpl#setV4.  My connection works fine with Socks5 but with Socks 4 i'm getting a number of Socket Exceptions.   For example:

```
java.net.SocketException: Malformed reply from SOCKS server
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.readSocksReply(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connectV4(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using the same snippet of code and point it to a different host? Capture the packets (Fiddler/Wireshark) from both implementations and compare the results?

Comment: seems like a wrong protocol used

Comment: @theMarceloR - we seem to only have the problem with one client.  i'm just wondering if anybody has seen any issues using Socks 4 in java, especially since the only way to get it to work is to use reflection.

Comment: `readSocksReply()` only throws that exception if the server has disconnected before sending all the expected data. Are you sure it's a SOCKS server at all? NB `SocksSocketImpl` should fall back to SOCKS V4 automatically if it doesn't get a SOCKS V5 reply from the server, so you shouldn't need to call `setV4()` at all.